# How to save data to SD card using Memory Shield Module SPI

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, arduino-ide, shields

I am trying to save some data to the SD card using the memory shield module that I read from HC-SR04 Ultrasonic Module. The data that gets printed indicates error. This is how my SD card module is connected.

> SD card attached to SPI bus as
>   VCC -Arduino 5v
>   GND- Arduino GND
>   MOSI - pin 11
>   MISO - pin 12
>   CLK - pin 13
>   CS - pin 4

Still, Arduino complains that there was an error opening the file in SD card. My sketch is this:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>
#define echoPin 6 // Echo Pin
#define trigPin 7 // Trigger Pin

int maximumRange = 250; // Maximum range needed
int minimumRange = 1; // Minimum range needed
long duration, distance; // Duration used to calculate distance
const int chipSelect = 4;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin (9600);
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);

  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");
  // see if the card is present and can be initialized:
  if (!SD.begin(chipSelect)) {
    Serial.println("Card failed, or not present");
    // don't do anything more:
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("card initialized.");
}

void loop() {
  readDistance();
  if(distance>minimumRange && distance < maximumRange){
    String string = "distance is" + distance;
    // open the file. note that only one file can be open at a time,
    // so you have to close this one before opening another.
    File dataFile = SD.open("datalog.txt", FILE_WRITE);
    // if the file is available, write to it:
    if( dataFile ){
      dataFile.println(string);
      dataFile.close();
      Serial.println( string );
    }else{
      // if the file isn't open, pop up an error:
      Serial.println("error opening datalog.txt");
      dataFile.close();
    }
  }else{
    Serial.println("Out of range...");
  }
  delay(50);
}

int readDistance(){
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW); 
  delayMicroseconds(2); 
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10); 
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  distance = duration/58.2;
}
```

Output:

```
rror opening datalog.txt
rror opening datalog.txt
error opening datalog.txt
rror opening datalog.txt
error opening datalog.txt
error opening datalog.txt
error opening datalog.txt
error opening datalog.txt
error opening datalog.txt
```

How do I solve this to save the readings to SD card?

Comment: Re-opening the file each time through the loop seems like a bad idea.  Unfortunately file system abstractions don't map very well to what you want to do.  You may want to write a number of readings, then re-open a file, perhaps with a different name in an incrementing pattern.  Or you could skip the filesystem and write to raw blocks.  Most practically, have a look at the code typically used with Arduino-based uSD data loggers and see what you can learn from how they handle it.

Comment: I think you have fried your SD card. Those cards operate at 3.3V and may not be 5V tolerant.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any print out based on this;

```
Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");
// see if the card is present and can be initialized:
if (!SD.begin(chipSelect)) {
  Serial.println("Card failed, or not present");
  // don't do anything more:
  return;
}
Serial.println("card initialized.");
```

Solution;

Try change

```
const int chipSelect = 4; // change value to 10
```

If not, try change the above code to;

```
Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");
if (!SD.begin(10)) {
  Serial.println("Initialization failed!");
  while (1);
}
Serial.println("Initialization done.");
```